# What’s this gearbox called?

Tags: control, gearing

[image: gearbox and motor removed]I took an apart a child’s toy because it looked like it had a neat gearbox in it, it did. The problem is I have no idea what type of gearbox is and I wanna see more things used with it.

It rotates both wheels forward when the motor goes in the forward direction. Thing weird thing is, when going in reverse it has one wheel go forward and one go backward is to turn the car.

Comment: so it has one wheel that always turns in one direction, and the other wheel that changes direction?

Comment: Is there a photo?

Comment: This is an interesting question, and an interesting mechanism. I too, would be interested in knowing the answer. I did try to work out what it's called, but as you probably found, there are so many results for completely inappropriate mechanisms that it was impossible to get anywhere. As with many identification question, this requires you to know what you're looking for before you can find it, which makes this an excellent question for the experts here in this community.

Comment: are you certain that both wheels turn when in reverse?

Comment: Interesting, so not diff based. I suspect the spring is significant. Does the cog move and/or compress the spring when running in reverse? Also, when running in reverse, do both wheels run at different speeds?

Comment: is there a gear that changes position when rotation direction changes? ... perhaps mounted on a lever

Comment: maybe it's here... http://507movements.com/

Comment: I've seen a lot of toys with a differential and a ratchet on one wheel.  This 1 motor solution allows the toy to both drive straight and turn.  When the motor goes forward, both wheels go forward.  But when the motor goes in reverse, a ratchet prevents one wheel from going in reverse.  So only one wheel reverses and the other is locked, and the toy turns while rotating backward around the locked wheel.

Comment: We should probably take this to chat, but I was assuming that if there had been a clicking sound, as if from a ratchet, when running in reverse, that this would have been mentioned. As it is, I can't see anything in the picture that suggests either a diff or a ratchet. I'd love to see what this looks like running forward and reverse. Even an animated gif would give us lots more information than a static image.

Comment: That thick cylindrical section looks a lot like it could be a clutch of some sort.  I suppose it could also be a diff, but it's much wider and shorter than other diffs I've seen.  However, it appears to be in the wrong place to where I'd expect a clutch or diff to be, considering that the thicker shaft (which might be coaxial?) is on the other side of the gearbox.

Comment: If you want this question to be re-opened @Ivan, please add the additional information requested in the comments, which might make this question answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what this is called, but my suspicion is that this mechanism makes use of something very similar to a differential gear.

When the drive shaft is rotating in one direction, the pinion gear (green) engages with the ring gear (blue) as normal, but when the drive shaft is rotating in the other direction, the pinion gear engages with an extended side gear (cyan) instead, while locking the ring gear in place.

Since the ring gear is fixed in place, the torque going into the side gear directly would be translated via the spider gears (orange) into torque in the  opposite direction on the other half shaft (red).

[image: Animated differential gear, click through for static version if link to animated version breaks]

Thanks to [Mallaky](https://auto.mallaky.com/differential/) for the animated gif.